# How to make spaces come in file

Tags: php, format, newline, whitespace

**I am trying to make a page which logs text with the time to a file.**

index.html:

```
<html>

<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<!-- <input name="field2" type="text" /> -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</html>
```

process.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1'])) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d His');
    $data = "\n" + "<pre>$date</pre>" + $_POST['field1'];
# if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
#    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
#    $filename = date('YmdHis').".txt";
    $filename = "log.txt";
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Cannot create file");
    }
    $ret = file_put_contents($filename, nl2br($data), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to $filename";
    }
}
else {
   die('No post data to process');
}
?>
```

log.txt:

```
0
```

When I input "test" log.txt shows "0".

How do I make it output the time and the text on a new line each time there is input.

Comment: In PHP, `+` is addition, not concatenation, so this is wrong: `"\n" + "<pre>$date</pre>" + $_POST['field1'];` Use a period instead.

Comment: You have several problems: 1) Troubleshoot your code to figure out why your form is only returning the character "0".  ["Echo" stmts](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp) can help.  2) Once you get "logs" working, it probably won't format in a browser like you expect.  You might want to parse your log into am HTML [<table>](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), or you might want to just keep it simple, and use the HTML [<code>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp) tag or [<pre>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp).

Comment: ALSO: "+" is wrong: `$data = "\n" + "<pre>$date</pre>" + $_POST['field1'];`.  Use "." to concatenate strings: `$data = "\n" . "<pre>$date</pre>" . $_POST['field1'];`.  And,like I said above, "\n" (newline) will *NOT* format like you might expect in your browser.

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `fopen` to create the file, and you could possibly lock it by doing so. `file_put_contents` will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

I removed + and replaced it with periods, I removed:

```
 if (!file_exists($filename)) {
       $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Cannot create file");
   }
```

because it was not needed, I removed pre tags because they were not needed.

process.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1'])) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d ');
    $data =  "\n" . "$date" . $_POST['field1'];
    $filename = "log.txt";
    $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to $filename";
    }
}
else {
   die('No post data to process');
}
?>
```

Now it outputs the data properly.

log.txt:

```
2021-06-22 test
```